# Add videos on ACF Gallery

Tags: php, image, video, gallery, advanced-custom-fields

I use [ACF Gallery](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/) for my portfolio website and I would like to **add some videos** in this gallery. 
I want to **keep the possibility to manage the order** of my medias, to mix videos and images. I'm not sure if I can add video between my images with the ACF Gallery plugin.
If not, which plugin can I use ?

The current code I use for my gallery :

```
            <div class='gallery'>

            <?php 

            $images = get_field('images_projet');

            if( $images ): ?>
                <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                    <?php $pb = $image['height'] / $image['width']; ?>

                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <div class="pb" style="padding-bottom: <?= $pb * 100 ?>%;"></div>
                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $image['caption']; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <div>
```

Comment: Ask this form ACF support team

Comment: you can use the repeater and radio/check box with conditional logic to use mixture of images and videos if you are having ACF Pro.